# Dynamically accessing the key value pair in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

I have a JSON,

```
"http": {
    "method": "POST",
    "headers": [{
        "content-type": "application/json"
    }, {
        "Authorization": "KKYZASSHUYTRJ"
    }],
    "url": "http://localhost:8888/download/context"
}
```

In this JSON, I need to access the headers and loop through the array. The keys of "headers" are dynamic. I need to access the keys as well as values. I need both keys and values to make a HTTP call. How can I do that in Typescript/Javascript

In all the Articles in Stackoverflow, I can able to see how to get the values using keys. Here I am asking how to retrieve keys as well as values.

I know that there is Object.getkeys() and Object.getValues() since these methods are not working in Safari, I am not choosing it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse JSON in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/parse-json-in-javascript)

Comment: Not a valid JSON.

Comment: @Oluwafemi I didn't pasted the entire JSON here. It is part of a huge JSON.

Comment: @Oluwafemi  He's maybe just cut and pasted the parts of the JSON he wanted to look at, all it needs is the opening and closing object literal, and it's valid.

Comment: @StephanBijzitter No it is not the duplicate of that thread

Comment: a.http.headers.forEach(function (o){Object.keys(o).forEach(function (key) { console.log(key,'=',o[key]); })})

Comment: You only need to use Object.keys, and that is supported in Safari.

Comment: @user2655966, then your question is unclear. I see a JSON string and you want to iterate over its keys; you need to parse it to an object first. As such, duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object.keys [is supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) in safari.

```
var data = {
    "http": {
        "method": "POST",
        "headers": [{"content-type": "application/json" },{ "Authorization": "KKYZASSHUYTRJ"}],
    "url": "http://localhost:8888/download/context"
    }
}


data["http"]["headers"].forEach(entry => console.log(Object.keys(entry)[0], entry[Object.keys(entry)[0]]))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to transpile this snippet you can easily switch the let/const declarations to var. I used a template string for the json, in practice you would probably get the value from some api, right?

```js
var json = JSON.parse(`
{
  "http": {
    "method": "POST",
    "headers": [{
        "content-type": "application/json"
    }, {
        "Authorization": "KKYZASSHUYTRJ"
    }],
    "url": "http://localhost:8888/download/context"
  }
}`);

if(typeof json.http !== "undefined" && typeof json.http["headers"] !== "undefined"){
  const headers = json.http["headers"];
  for(let i = 0; i < headers.length; ++i){
    for(let key in headers[i]){
      console.log(key, ":", headers[i][key])
    }
  }
}
```